# Inno Setup: WizardForm.StatusLabel color

Tags: inno-setup

How to change StatusLabel color for Inno Setup correctly? I've tried next options:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
  begin
     WizardForm.StatusLabel.Font.Color := $8D7C72;  
  end;
end;
```

and

```
procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
begin  
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Installing, please wait...';
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Font.Color := $8D7C72;
end;
```

But it didn't help.

On the screen below, I've set color for WizardForm.StatusLabel and custom percent label. But it works only for the second one.
Also I use [VclStyleInno](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) to style my installer.
[image]

Comment: Just a TLabel, which shows progress of installation.

Comment: but when I turn off vcl styler, the problem still the same. I use Inno Setup 5.5.9 (u)

Comment: Show us a screenshot with styling turned off.

Comment: What version of Windows? (though I doubt it matters)

Answer (score 0):

Your code (the `CurPageChanged`) works for me for a plain un-styled installer.

[image]

So it's probably the styling that breaks it.

Note that the `StatusLabel` is `TNewStaticText`, not `TLabel`. So if the `TLabel` works correctly, just hide the `StatusLabel` and create another custom `TLabel` instead.

Comment: yeah, I think that in my case I'll create custom label.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use TLabel or TNewStaticText?

Some time ago you mentioned you use Graphical Installer for styling (with VCL Styles). In GI you can use new **TextColor** property for **TNewStatictext** which overrides *Font.Color* and *Color* properties.

Example:

```
URLLabel.TextColor := clRed
```

TLabel has no changes so it accepts *Font.Color* and *Color*.

Comment: Nope, I'm using only VCLInooSetup, without GI.
And WizardForm.StatusLabel is TNewStaticText.

Answer (score 0):

As turned out, all I needed to do - is re-install Inno Setuup.